# Respeaker Core v2.0 with Google Assistant

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I am using Respeaker core v2.0 with Google Assistant and trying to install the Google Assistant SDK and run the sample code:
http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Google_Assistant/

I am referring to the steps involved in the above links. After generating the credentials and providing access to the model. I have installed the Respeakerd which is the last step of the above documentation and also cloned the GitHub repo. But when I am giving the below command:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

I am getting this error:

> error: click 7.1.1 is installed but click<7,>=6.7; extra == "samples"
>   is required by set(['google-assistant-sdk'])

[image]
And finally when I am trying to activate the google assistant I am getting this output as below which is not expected:
[image]

I have installed all the dependencies correctly. I don’t know where am I going wrong. Can somebody please help me fix this?

Comment: What version of the Google Assistant SDK do you install?

Comment: Hi Nick, I am using the latest version of Google Assistant SDK

Comment: Given the age of the tutorial and the Respeaker wrapper, it may be preferable to use an earlier version.

Comment: Ok, let me try downgrading the version and see if it works. I have one more doubt in Google Assistant Set-Up guide it is mentioned that we need to create a python virtual environment and then try installing the Google Assistant SDK but in the Respeaker documentation its mention that respeaker use the pydbus library, which depends on the gi.repository library, it's not easy to install gi.repository in a python virtual env. And the system of ReSpeaker has this library builtin. So it is advised  to skip the python virutal env setup. Do you think skipping the virtual env setup can be an issue?

Comment: If you don't use a virtual environment you may run into a mismatch with library versions you have throughout your system. That may cause an issue if you have a lot of Python projects.